# print a specific div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I m using a javascript code that print a specific div.. This code is working fine but it shows a header url and footer automatically when i print it... I can handle it from chrome browser but not from ie or firefox.please help

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function printDiv() {
             var divElements = document.getElementById('print_id').innerHTML;
            var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

            document.body.innerHTML ="<html><head><title>Booking</title> </head><body>"+divElements+"</body></html>" ;

            window.print();

            document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: it is not possible because you are in the same page, you have to hide the div's which all used for displaying header and footer.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Where do you want to print it and what's exactly the problem? Can you post an example of how it doesn't work please?

Comment: The header and footer you describe are what the browser places on the print, as far as I know you cannot get rid of these. You can of course create a PDF file or something and let the user save this on his/her computer and then print it. This way you'll not be printing from the browser, omitting the header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control printing of headers and footers inside your page as they are controlled by browser preferences.

You can change the preferences on your machine (firefox and IE) via the guide [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/the-geek-blog/prevent-firefox-or-internet-explorer-from-printing-the-url-on-every-page/)

Note: This only changes your local settings and won't affect users printing your page on their machines.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printDiv() {    
var printContents = document.getElementById('Your printable div').innerHTML;
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
 document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
 window.print();
 document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```