# Trouble in printing a div content with text fields using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the div which i have been print.

```
<div id="leftdes">In order to purchase and obtain a copy of your certified IRS Transcript for the year </strong>
  <div>
    AUTHORIZED SIGNATURE ________________________________ 
    <input title="Enter Date" name="aut_date" id="aut_date" type="text"  value="" onClick="rem_valid(this.id);"/>
  </div>
  <div class="search-raw" style="width:98%;">
    <select title="Select Suffix" name="a_suff" id="a_suff" class="input-4" style="padding:5px;" onClick="rem_valid(this.id);">
      <option value="" selected="selected">SUFFIX</option>
      <option value="Jr">Jr</option>
      <option value="Sr">Sr</option>
      <option value="I">I</option>
      <option value="II">II</option>
      <option value="III">III</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input title="Enter Company Name" name="a_cname" id="a_cname" type="text"  value="" onClick="rem_valid(this.id);"/></br></br>
</div>
```

I am trying to print the above **div** using javascript code below. But iam not getting the values of input fields. Help me to getout of this problem.

```
function printdiv(divid)
{
  var divElements = document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML;
  //var name="US Background Check";
  var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
  var current=document.body.innerHTML = "<html><head><title></title></head><body><img src='images/logo.png'/></br>"+divElements+"</body>";
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML=oldPage;
}
```

Print function "printdiv" called when click on this below button.

```
<input name="but" id="but1" type="button"   value="PRINT"  onClick="printdiv('leftdes');"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242938/print-a-specific-div-using-javascript. But it doesn't have a solution though

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can't fetch the values of the fields this way. However, you get their *default* values, not those typed by the user.

What happens is the following : when the page loads, the fields are filled with their default values ("" for the text fields, and the first option for the drop-down menu). Then, when the user changes those fields, **the attributes of your HTML tags never change**, they keep their default values.

In other words, when you call `document.getElementById(divid)`, it returns the HTML code that was initially loaded. If you manually change the values by typing, you don't see those changes.

One of the simplest solutions would be to access those values, and, inside your function, when you change the content of the `body`, just place those values instead of the HTML you get from `document.getElementById(divid)`.

```
var aut_date = document.getElementById("aut_date").value;
var a_suff = document.getElementById("a_suff").value;
var a_cname = document.getElementById("a_cname").value;

document.body.innerHTML = "... <input ... value='"+ aut_date +"' ...> etc.";
```

By the way, you don't need to add those `<html><head><title></title></head><body>` when you do `var current=document.body.innerHTML =`, since you're already *inside* the `body` element. Right now, you're placing an HTML document, a header and a page title inside the body... You should also not end your string with `</body>`, for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
function printDiv(divName) {
    var inpText = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = inpText;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = inpText;
    }
```